# Prevent span being inside another span with insertNode

Tags: javascript

I have this code. On select of text, a div that contains colors will appear. On click of one of the colors, the selected text will contain that highlight. However, how can I check if the highlight is inside another highlight? If the highlight is inside another highlight, I want an alert to appear that this action isn't possible. Otherwise, the highlight will be created.

**NOTE:** You can completely ignore the html and css section.

This is an example of a highlight within a highlight. I highlighted the phrase `There Hello There Hello There Hello` with yellow. Then, I highlighted inside the yellow highlighter `e Hello There There Hello`.

[image]

```js
$("#tooltip").mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

//Only add the listener once, not another listener each mouseup
$(".boxes").click(function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement("span");
  node.classList.add($(this).attr("data-mark"));
  node.appendChild(contents);
  // Go ahead and create the span
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
  hideTooltip();
});
function hideTooltip() {
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = ''; //hide the tooltip
}
$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    // Tool Tip
    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
      //this will place ele below the selection
      ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
      //this will align the right edges together
      ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';
      //code to set content
      ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // End of Tool Tip
  }
});
```

```css
/* Highlighting */
.blue_mark {
  background: #AAF6FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red_mark {
  background: #FF9B9F;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.green_mark {
  background: #D6FFAA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow_mark {
  background: #FFF8AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.orange_mark {
  background: #FFBF98;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.purple_mark {
  background: #D7D5FC;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* End of Highlighting */

/* Tool Kit */
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: grey solid 1px;
  background: #373737;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
#cal2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}
#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}
#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}
#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}
#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}
#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
/* End of Tool Kit */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>Hello There Hello There Hello There Hello There! Hello There</span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue' data-mark='blue_mark'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green' data-mark='green_mark'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box' class='boxes' title='Yellow' data-mark='yellow_mark'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange' data-mark='orange_mark'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple' data-mark='purple_mark'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red' data-mark='red_mark'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add another class like `marked` to all the colored spans. Then before you mark a selectin, check whether the selection is in a span with `class="marked"`.

Comment: Do you also need to check for the case where someone tries to mark a selection that contains an already-marked selection?

Comment: @Barmar It would be nice to check already marked selection. If you do try, the application works fine, but the code gets messy: `<span class="green_mark" ><span class="green_mark" ><span class="orange_mark">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the select to start and end in the same node, and check the parent:

```
var verse = document.getElementById("actual_verse");
if(range.startContainer !== range.endContainer ||
   range.startContainer.parentElement !== verse ||
   range.endContainer.parentElement !== verse
) {
  alert("Not possible");
  return;
}
```

```js
var verse = document.getElementById("actual_verse");

$("#tooltip").mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

//Only add the listener once, not another listener each mouseup
$(".boxes").click(function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if(range.startContainer !== range.endContainer ||
     range.startContainer.parentElement !== verse ||
     range.endContainer.parentElement !== verse
  ) {
    alert("Not possible");
    return;
  }
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement("span");
  node.classList.add($(this).attr("data-mark"));
  node.appendChild(contents);
  // Go ahead and create the span
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
  hideTooltip();
});
function hideTooltip() {
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = ''; //hide the tooltip
}
$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    // Tool Tip
    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
      //this will place ele below the selection
      ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
      //this will align the right edges together
      ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';
      //code to set content
      ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // End of Tool Tip
  }
});
```

```css
/* Highlighting */
.blue_mark {
  background: #AAF6FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red_mark {
  background: #FF9B9F;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.green_mark {
  background: #D6FFAA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow_mark {
  background: #FFF8AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.orange_mark {
  background: #FFBF98;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.purple_mark {
  background: #D7D5FC;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* End of Highlighting */

/* Tool Kit */
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: grey solid 1px;
  background: #373737;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
#cal2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}
#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}
#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}
#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}
#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}
#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
/* End of Tool Kit */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>Hello There Hello There Hello There Hello There! Hello There</span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue' data-mark='blue_mark'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green' data-mark='green_mark'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box' class='boxes' title='Yellow' data-mark='yellow_mark'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange' data-mark='orange_mark'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple' data-mark='purple_mark'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red' data-mark='red_mark'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great try, but the code doesn't seem to work at all... I can do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cO4Wo.png).

Comment: @GreatDayToday Works for me

Comment: I get it. If you highlight _inside_ the highlight, your code works. However, if you start the highlight outside of the area and then go into the area. Once you are done, the span previously outside is now on the inside of the newly created span...

Comment: Maybe a picture would help explain my thinking. Is it possible to prevent [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C6SmJ.png)? I first created the orange highlighting, then went outside of the orange highlight and made the red highlight surround the orange highlight...

Comment: @GreatDayToday I see. I forgot a check. The start and end nodes should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works on firefox, but I haven't tried other browsers.

```js
var verse = document.getElementById("actual_verse");

$("#tooltip").mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

//Only add the listener once, not another listener each mouseup
$(".boxes").click(function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if(range.startContainer !== range.endContainer ||
     range.startContainer.parentElement !== verse ||
     range.endContainer.parentElement !== verse
  ) {
    alert("Not possible");
    return;
  }
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement("span");
  node.classList.add($(this).attr("data-mark"));
  node.appendChild(contents);
  // Go ahead and create the span
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
  hideTooltip();
});
function hideTooltip() {
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = ''; //hide the tooltip
}
$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    // Tool Tip
    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
     if(sel.anchorNode != sel.focusNode){
     alert('highlight already exists!');
      return;
    }
    
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
      //this will place ele below the selection
      ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
      //this will align the right edges together
      ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';
      //code to set content
      ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // End of Tool Tip
  }
});
```

```css
/* Highlighting */
.blue_mark {
  background: #AAF6FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red_mark {
  background: #FF9B9F;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.green_mark {
  background: #D6FFAA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow_mark {
  background: #FFF8AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.orange_mark {
  background: #FFBF98;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.purple_mark {
  background: #D7D5FC;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* End of Highlighting */

/* Tool Kit */
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: grey solid 1px;
  background: #373737;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
#cal2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}
#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}
#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}
#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}
#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}
#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
/* End of Tool Kit */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>Hello There Hello There Hello There Hello There! Hello There</span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue' data-mark='blue_mark'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green' data-mark='green_mark'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box' class='boxes' title='Yellow' data-mark='yellow_mark'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange' data-mark='orange_mark'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple' data-mark='purple_mark'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red' data-mark='red_mark'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added a test after get the selection.
The documentation is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection